# How to make a vCard DTO convertible in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, dto, vcf-vcard, microformats

What would be the easiest way to make a DTO in java that represents a vCard? 
I want this DTO to be sent as an xCard (XML version of this object).
I could use a xCard schema (.xsd) to generate my java object but I can't find such .xsd
I guess a Relax NG schema could do the trick too.

I would use that vCardDto to be nested into another DTO and send as a jersey Response.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you programming in?  [ez-vcard](http://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) is a vCard library for Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but I need a real DTO that could be transformed into an xml object by JAXB to be sent in an http response by jersey.
For the details, I tried to use an ezVcard and marshall it myself by customizing JAXB, but my vCard is nested into another DTO and JAXB takes the whole object to be marshalled.
I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, there is a standard called "xCard", which is for encoding vCards in XML.  ez-vcard supports that standard.